# On the distribution of sugar on water

Tags: density, molecular-dynamics

How could I get a function (at least a good approximation of it)that describes the density of the sugared water in relation with time and the dimensions of the container that holds the water? Consider that the sugar is sprinkled on the surface of the water. Fell free to use powdered or granulated sugar as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the second law of thermodynamics and diffusion, entropy of this system will increase and, when time approaches infinity, the sugar distribution should be uniform, if dimensions of the container are finite.